# Exclude classes with @Data notation from Jacoco plugin analysis in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

I have a project in Jenkins which I want to get its code coverage using [Jacoco Code Coverage Plugin of Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin).

There are some classes in my source code with `@Data` notation which should be excluded from Jacoco analysis for some reason.

All include/exclude examples in the internet are performing at class/folder level directly; none of them are pointing to an attribute of the class. Is there any way to do so? Any solution with Jenkins plugins (not only Jacoco) is acceptable.

Comment: as I know jacoco plugin doesn't provide any way to exclude classes by annotation. I suggest to move all @Data classes to specific package(s) and then exclude them using package address.

Comment: @Data is a lombok annotation. this may be helpful: https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/ignoring-lombok-code-in-jacoco/

Answer (score 1):

Place a file "lombok.config" in the root of your project with the configuration [addLombokGeneratedAnnotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration). This will be automatically recognized by [JaCoCo 0.8.0](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/releases/tag/v0.8.0) onwards.

```
# Root of your project, in a default Maven-project, would contain pom.xml
$ cat lombok.config 
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```